# Just because there is a conjugation chart, doesn't mean all forms are common?

Tags: gramática

I'm been studying Spanish for a while now and am aware that some verb tenses or moods are "generally" used only in some legal situations or literature, eg.  the future subjunctive.  However, just considering these tenses/moods

indicative - present | preterite | imperfect | conditional | future 
subjunctive - present | imperfect

Would it be accurate to say that not all verbs in those forms are going to be common to see every conjugated form used?  I made a previous post about the verb Haber, and this made me think that I am starting to see a trend here.  In "general", not all conjugated forms of a verb are going to be commonly used, as there might be a more common way to say  the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spanish, there are at least three tenses that are hardly ever used, their use being restricted to old texts and to legal jargon and some stilted literary forms (e.g. the Bible). They are:

- Pretérito anterior del indicativo (hube/hubiste/hubo/hubimos/hubisteis/hubieron + participle). As the name says, this tense was used to refer to a past action immediately previous to another past action: *Cuando **hubo llegado** a la casa, se le acercaron los ciegos.* (Upon arriving at the house, the blind people approached him.) In everyday language, we would say: Cuando llegó a la casa, se le acercaron los ciegos.
- Futuro imperfecto del subjuntivo (the ending will be *-are/-ere* and its variants according to the person): This could be used to refer to an uncertain future event in a subordinate clause. E.g. *Si **existieren** dudas al respecto, no deberás actuar.* (Should there be any doubts in that respect, you shall abstain from doing anything.) In everyday language, this tense is replaced with the Pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo: Si existier**a**n dudas al respecto, no deberás actuar.
- Futuro perfecto del subjuntivo (hubiere/hubieres/hubiéremos/hubiereis/hubieren + participle): This could be used to refer to an uncertain future event previous to another future event. E.g. *Cuando **hubieres encontrado** la verdad, no la dejes ir.* (Once you have found the truth, do not let go of it.) In everyday language, this tense is replaced with the Pretérito Perfecto del subjuntivo: Cuando hayas encontrado la verdad, no la dejes ir.

Comment: thank you.  Yes, I seem to gather that those tenses you mention are not used often as well.  However, for the tenses/moods that I mentioned above, are there some verbs that are rarely used in a particular conjugation?  For example, in the childrens video (great learning tool) "the bird and the whale", the very first scentence uses Haber in the preterite, eg.  "Una vez hubo un pájaro que amaba a una ballena."  Is this, or the 2nd person plural form hubimos very common? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNHuttMfnwM

Comment: The answer to the question above can be found in the reply and comments of this other question of yours: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/42975/haber-vs-estar-in-2nd-or-3rd-person-plural-preterite

Comment: "Hubo" alone is very usual. "Hubieron" alone is ungrammatical.

Comment: thank you again.  This is a good example that I think highlights my original question, that just because a verb has a particular conjugation, doesnt mean its actually used.  So then is it accurate to say that a conjugation chart is simply filling out the variations of a conjugation based on grammar rules?  Its rather confusing if a conjugated form is in a chart yet its not valid grammar?

Comment: sorry I just re-read your last reply.  I think I understand what youre saying now.  Hubieron, while not used by itself, its conjugation is used for those other tenses, eg past perfect etc.   Thanks again